# Object Method Chainning

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods, method-chaining

```
function modifyFunction(f) {
    return function () {
        var returnValue = f.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log(returnValue);
        if (returnValue == undefined) {
            return this;
        } else {
            return returnValue;
        }
    };
}

function modifyMethod(o, m) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(m)) {
        if (o[m] instanceof Function) {
            o[m] = modifyFunction(m);
        }
    }
}

var o = {
    num: 0,
    add: function (x) {
        return this.num += x;
    },
    sub: function (x) {
        return this.num -= x;
    }
};

modifyMethod(o, "add");
o.add(2).add(4);
console.log(o.num); // o.num = 6
modifyMethod(o, "sub");

o.sub(1).add(3).sub(5);
console.log(o.num); // o.num = 3
```

How would I make it so that in modifyMethod function inside of the "if(o[m] instanceof Function)" would be equal to what returns by the modifyFunction function, when sending it o[m]? I am trying to make it so that it is chainable, yet I am having a very difficult time getting my head around this.

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? It's unclear to me what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To make `o.add(2).add(4);` equal to `o.add(2); o.add(4);` We can observe that what `o.add(2)` returns should be `o`. So your `modifyFunction` should return a function that :

1. call the passed in function with given parameters.
2. Return the caller.

So instead of return that `returnValue`(which is o.num, a number), you should always return `this`.

Another point is that in your `modifyMethod`, after you checked if `o[m]` is a function, you should pass in that function, not `m` which is just the key. So it should be `o[m] = modifyFunction(o[m]);`

```js
function modifyFunction(f) {
    return function () {
        var returnValue = f.apply(this, arguments);
        // Return the object that call this function, 
        // so it becomes chainable.
        return this;
    };
}

function modifyMethod(o, m) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(m)) {
        if (o[m] instanceof Function) {
            // Pass o[m], not m, m is a string.
            o[m] = modifyFunction(o[m]);
        }
    }
}

var o = {
    num: 0,
    add: function (x) {
        return this.num += x;
    },
    sub: function (x) {
        return this.num -= x;
    }
};

modifyMethod(o, "add");
o.add(2).add(4);
console.log(o.num); // o.num = 6
modifyMethod(o, "sub");

o.sub(1).add(3).sub(5);
console.log(o.num); // o.num = 3
```